# TerrSet Errors - Data Path Not Found

Tags: file-path

I've been trying to struggle through Terrset but just can't get it to do what I want. I initially had problems downloading the files from geoexplorer but seem to have figured that out. The problem now is that I deleted my original project file with the intention of starting fresh. However, I'm now getting errors whenever I open Terrset and also when I try to start a new project. When opening Terrset I get the following errors:

Data path not found. Please select another project or change the data path.

There is an inconsistency in the user's preference file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Terrset\TerrSetUsers.ini", line "projectdir=C:\Users\jdleh\Documents\Romote Sensing\lab2pt2". That folder does not exist

When I try to select a new project in the project tab I get the following error:

Cannot create file "C:\Users\jdleh\Documents\Remote Sensing\lab2pt2\lab2pt4.env". The system cannot find the path specified

Any thoughts on these errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move the files to the desktop. Use short name for the data folder. Lab2 might be a good start. Also, make sure you have no spaces between words used in folder /sub directory names. For example after Documents, you data path includes Remote Sensing with a space separating these two words. 
hope this works.

Check that your installation is OK.

Try manually navigating to any file and displaying it.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. You're right. I needed to eliminate the space. I also was not creating the correct file path using the change projects folder. I appreciate your fast response!